# how to define the changing scope name?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var tags_offset=[];
$scope.getRelations = function(id, ref, subRef=0){

    tags_offset[ref+'-'+subRef]=0;
    $http.get( CONS.appHttp+ '/tags.php?ID='+id
         +'&ref='+ref
         +'&contentType='+subRef
         +'&offset='+tags_offset[0] ).success(function( data ){
             if(tags_offset > 0){
                 $scope.tagRelations[ref+'-'+subRef] = $scope.tagRelations[ref+'-'+subRef].concat( angular.fromJson( data ));
                 $scope.tagRelations[ref+'-'+subRef].next = data.next;
                tags_offset[ref+'-'+subRef]++;
             }else{

                 $scope.tagRelations[ref+'-'+subRef] = angular.fromJson( data );
                 tags_offset[ref+'-'+subRef]++;
             }
    });
}
```

I want this format
$scope.tagRelations.((ref+'-'+subRef))
for example

```
$scope.tagRelations.content-1

$scope.tagRelations.video-2
```

I want changing `$scope.tagRelations[ref+'-'+subRef]`
...........................................................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Dot notation only allows you to access properties which have names that are valid identifiers. `-` is not a character that can appear in an identifier because it is an operator ([the subtraction operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-subtraction-operator-minus)).

You must use square bracket notation to access properties which have names which are not valid identifiers.